# NHibernate one-to-many on joined-subclass inherited property

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, nhibernate, orm

I am using NHibernate 3.3.3 with .Net 4.0 and am facing the problem that NHibernate generates wrong SQL.

I have got following (simplified) classes:

```csh
class Process 
{
    public Customer { get; set; }
    [additional properties]
}

class OrderProcess : Process 
{
    [further additional properties]
}

class FinishedProcess : Process 
{
    public DateTime SaveOn { get; set; }
}

class FinishedOrderProcess : FinishedProcess 
{
    [even more properties]
}

class Customer 
{
    public IList<OrderProcess> OrdersInProgess { get; set; }
    public IList<FinisheOrderProcess> FinishedOrders { get; set;}
    [additional properties]
}
```

Using those classes i have mapped them using hbm.xml files for NHibernate in the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="tadoraOrm"
                   namespace="tadoraOrm.Models">

  <class name="Customer" table="CUSTOMER">
      <id column="REC_ID" name="Id">
          <generator class="identity" />
      </id>
      <bag name="FinishedOrders" inverse="true" cascade="none" lazy="true">
          <key column="CUSTOMER_ID"/>
          <one-to-many class="FinishedOrderProcess"/>
      </bag>
      <bag name="OrdersInProgess" inverse="true" cascade="none" lazy="true">
          <key column="CUSTOMER_ID"/>
          <one-to-many class="OrderProcess"/>
      </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="tadoraOrm"
                   namespace="tadoraOrm.Models">
    <class name="Process" table="PROCESS" abstract="true">
        <id name="Id" column="REC_ID">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <joined-subclass name="FinishedProcess" table="FINISHED_PROCESS" abstract="true">
            <key column="PROCESS_ID"/>
            <joined-subclass name="FinishedOrderProcess" table="FINISHED_ORDER_PROCESS">
                <key column="FINISHED_PROCESS_ID"/>
            </joined-subclass>
        </joined-subclass>
        <joined-subclass name="OrderProcess" table="ORDER_PROCESS">
            <key column="ORDER_PROCESS_ID"/>
        </joined-subclass>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Last but not least here is the code (in VB.Net) for getting all

```
Dim customers As IList(Of Customer) = session.CreateCriteria(Of Customer)().
    CreateAlias("FinishedOrders", "FO").
        Add(
            Restrictions.Between("FO.SavedOn", dtpFrom.Value.Date, dtpUntil.Value)
        ).List<Customer>()
```

This whole thing generates this SQL:

```
select
    *
from CUSTOMER C 
  inner join FINISHED_ORDER_PROCESS FOP 
    on C.REC_ID = FOP.CUSTOMER_ID
  left outer join FINISHED_PROCESS FP
    on FP.PROCESS_ID = FOP.FINISHED_PROCESS_ID
  left outer join PROCESS P
    on P.REC_ID = FP.PROCESS_ID
where FP.SavedOn between '2013-10-01T00:00:00' /* @p0 */ and '2013-10-08T17:53:50' /* @p1 */
```

The problem here is that FOP does not contain a column CUSTOMER_ID it is contained in the PROCESS table. Further more I would expect the all joins to be inner joins instead of left outer joins for the last two tables.

Basicly this:

```
select
    *
from CUSTOMER C 
  inner join FINISHED_ORDER_PROCESS FOP 
    on C.REC_ID = P.CUSTOMER_ID
  inner join FINISHED_PROCESS FP
    on FP.PROCESS_ID = FOP.FINISHED_PROCESS_ID
  inner join PROCESS P
    on P.REC_ID = FP.PROCESS_ID
where FP.SavedOn between '2013-10-01T00:00:00' /* @p0 */ and '2013-10-08T17:53:50' /* @p1 */
```

I'm sorry for posting that much code but I think it explains the problem I am facing the best way possible.

The reason for using such an inheritance strategy is that I have got several different processes apart from orders which work in the similar ways.

If you have got an idea how to retrieve a list of customers who have got FOPs in the specified time frame using either NHibernate Criteria API, HQL or any other possibility using NHibernate I would be gratefull if you could share.

If any information is missing or the question seems incomprehensible feel free to ask!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we have to do in this case, is correctly navigate NHibernate, where is the *object relation* i.e. **table relationship**. The relation in this case is defined on the base class `Process`, on the table `Process`.

So, the mapping should be like this:

```
<bag name="FinishedOrders" inverse="true" cascade="none" lazy="true">
    <key column="CUSTOMER_ID"/>

    <!-- instead of that -->
    <!-- <one-to-many class="FinishedOrderProcess"/>-->

    <!-- use this -->
    <one-to-many class="Process"/>
</bag>
```

Edit: In this case, the mapping of the `Process` collections (*Customer* entity) must be changed to be `IList<Process>`. This in fact relates to the current DB design, where relation Customer to Process is defined on that Process abstract level

Ad discussed below, the short term solution, could be to leave the `.net` mapping as it is, if we will introduce the WHERE attribute. If we have enough information during the mapping (e.g. in the *Process* table) we can distinguish which rows will be loaded as `FinishedOrders`, therefore avoid the casting exception.

Comment: First off thank you for your interest in my request.

Comment: Couldn't edit the comment anymore... I already tried your suggestion and it indeed generates correct SQL. But then i have the problem that all processes are listed in the relationship. This results in a conversion error when trying to fill the IList<FinishedOrderProcess> because e.g. OfferProcess (one of the other mentioned processes) correctly polymorph to the appropriate class. Maybe this was not clear in my first post.

Comment: I see. This is the only way how to navigate NHibernate to make the relation correctly. What we most likely should do is to change the C# mapping to expect `Process` *(the base class)* because that's how the relationship works in your DB model. It could be *protected* property. Then create some computed, *virtual* collections which are filtering that collection based on the real type. Inheritance in this scenario, seems to be more bringing complexity then profit. Other possibility is use the WHERE attribute, if there are enough information in the Process table how to distinguish the class

Comment: I will probably dodge the problem at this time using the where attribute. In long term i will refactor the inheritance though. Would you please make your last comment an answer so i can mark it as solved/answered?

Comment: That makes sense. NHibernate is really powerful tool ;)